# Question in implementing Trie data structure

Tags: java, oop, trie

I have a question about nested class in terms of Trie implementation

I want to know what is the difference define TrieNode class inside of Trie class and outside of Trie class

In case of I implement TrieNode class outside of Trie class, when I try to use Insert method, it keeps sayig NullPointException at (Trie.java:14),

So anyone could explain about what are the difference between two way and further to what is the solution if i want to resolve Nullpointexception error when I implement TrieNode class outside of Trie class.

here is my code

```
public class Trie {

    private final TrieNode root;
    public Trie () {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void insert (String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            TrieNode node = current.children.get(ch);
            if (node == null) {
                node = new TrieNode();
                current.children.put(ch, node);
            }
            current = node;
        }
        //mark the current nodes endOfWord as true
        current.isEnd = true;
}

    public boolean search (String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            if (current.children.get(ch) == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = current.children.get(ch);
        }

        return current.isEnd;
    }

    public void delete (String word) {
        delete(root, word, 0);
    }

    private boolean delete (TrieNode node, String word, int index) {
        if (index == word.length()) {
            if (!node.isEnd) {
                return false;
            }
            node.isEnd = false;

            return node.children.size() == 0;
        }
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        node = node.children.get(word.charAt(index));
        boolean shouldBeDeleted = delete(node, word, index + 1);

        if (shouldBeDeleted) {
            node.children.remove(word.charAt(index));
            return node.children.size() == 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Trie trie = new Trie();
        trie.insert("abcd");
      //  System.out.println(trie.search("abcd"));
    }
}
```

TrieNode class separated to Trie class

```
public class TrieNode {
    boolean isEnd;
    Map<Character, TrieNode> children;
    public void TrieNode () {
        this.isEnd = false;
        this.children = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: One (probably the only) significant difference (and an explanation for this type of exception): The inner class "has reference" on an outer object/class (by default) ... but i still don't see, where you use it....to fix your problem delete the `void` in `TrieNode`.

Comment: since, that is *not* what you call, when `root = new TrieNode();` ;) ..leaving `children == null` ..causing the nullpointer excpetion

Comment: it became clear now ! but even if I write TrieNode class separate with Trie class, it still works same after I delete "void", is there still difference between those two?